# "Gradle --> Refresh Gradle Project" in Eclipse removes classpath entries

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have a Gradle (6.6.1) project on Eclipse with Gradle Buildship 3.0.

When I do a project refresh (Gradle --> Refresh Gradle Project), my classpath entries are wiped out (Project Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries).

I can get them back by running the gradle task "eclipse". But, why do they disappear on refreshing the project? Is there a way to customize what happens when I do the Gradle Project Refresh ? If I can just run the "eclipse" gradle task as part of that project refresh.

Comment: Do you have a customised `eclipse` task? This should not be necessary. [Does this answer your question?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/buildship-3-1-is-now-available/31600)

Comment: Yes, I do have a customized eclipse task. Would that be the issue? I do need it because I have customization on preferences on facets.

Comment: Maybe. Please show your `build.gradle`. Why do you need this? Is sharing the project settings not enough?